# Is there a way to show a list which based on a ListView Template?

Tags: python, django, listview

What I want to do is to show a list based on a search that user made. I created a method to filter objects and inserted in a global variable(BTW, I don't know if it is good to do this in Django/Python.) And based on this global variable I want to show the list of objects based on ListView Template. Is it possible? If not, how can I do?

```
search_objects = Model()

def search(request):
    search_objects = Model.objects.filter(field1__icontains=search_text) | 
                     Model.objects.filter(fiedl2__icontains=search_text) | 
                     Model.objects.filter(field3__icontains=search_text)
```

Comment: You **must absolutely definitely not** use a global variable for this.

Comment: Ok, I imagined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course can, you can see this example below;

```
from django.views import generic
from django.db.models import Q

from yourapp.models import ModelName

class SearchView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'yourapp/search.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.query = self.request.GET.get('q') # `search_text`
        try:
            return ModelName.objects.filter(
                Q(field1__icontains=self.query) |
                Q(field2__icontains=self.query) |
                Q(field3__icontains=self.query)
            ) #.order_by('-created')
        except: # handle if query is `None`
            return ModelName.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['query'] = self.query
        return context_data
```

Check this source [ListView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) for more information.

Comment: After duplicating the same HTML(by creating a search.html) as my original list view and applying your solution, worked as expected! Thanks!